# Mysql SELECT - How to select a column as an 'UNSELECTED' column?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables which contain many columns. example of my tables:

```
table1
_______________________________________________
| a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i | ... | z |
-----------------------------------------------
table2
_______________________________________________
| a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i | ... | z |
-----------------------------------------------
```

And now, I want to copy or insert a record from table1 to table 2. This is my query :

```
INSERT INTO table2 
SELECT table1.* FROM table1
WHERE table1.b = '1'
```

I don't find any errors in query, but all I want is **insert a record from all columns except column 'a' in table 1 to table2**.
I can do it by this query :

```
INSERT INTO table2 (b,c,d,...)  // it takes a long line
SELECT table1.b,table1.c,table1.d,... FROM table1 // it takes a long line
WHERE table1.b = '1'
```

But this is not an efficient query line, because i just don't select 1 column.
Is there any efficient way?

Comment: There is no "select all but" functionality in SQL. Either you `select * `, or list the fields you DO want.

Comment: workaround: have ALL of the columns in table1 in table2, do a `select *`, then alter table1 and drop the unwanted column(s). it's ugly/hackish, but it's good for the lazy types who don't want to type out field names.

Comment: why not update set a=null (or whatever the default is) after you insert ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try duplicating the table with a create like statement, then alter it to drop the columns you don't want and do the insert into select with that new table. Then drop that new table. (or use a temp table)

```
CREATE TABLE table3 LIKE table1

ALTER TABLE table3 DROP COLUMN x

INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table3

DROP TABLE table3
```

and so forth.